# Solr index upgradation from 1.4.1 to 5.2.1

Tags: apache, hadoop, solr, migration, web-crawler

I am facing a problem to upgrade solr version. Currently we are using 1.4.1 version which is quite old and need to be updated to 5.2.1 version. I have set up  the new version locally however when I tried to copy paste the old data into core's i.e collection1/data/index folder it started throwing exception regarding  the indexing format. Is there any way to upgrade the index format compatible with 5.2.1 version with out data lose ?

Comment: After installing new version, have you created a collection? If not create a collection. Then stop the solr. Copy the index files alone to the new collection folder. Then, Start solr. It should bring up ideally

Comment: Yes i did the same but it come up with exception of not supported index format.

Answer (score 1):

Solr docs says Solr 5 stops supporting Solr 3.x or earlier indexes. You need to run the Lucene IndexUpdater provided with Solr 4.10.

Quotes from [Solr Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5):

> Solr 5 has no support for reading Lucene/Solr 3.x and earlier indexes.
>   Be sure to run the Lucene IndexUpgrader included with Solr 4.10 if you
>   might still have old 3x formatted segments in your index.
>   Alternatively: fully optimize your index with Solr 4.10 to make sure
>   it consists only of one up-to-date index segment.